# Using just one output of a J-K flip-flop

Tags: flipflop

If I am using a J-K flip-flop, but only need one of the outputs, what should I do with the other?

Leave it disconnected, or tie it high/low (via a resistor?) Why?

Comment: Generally you never tie unconnected **outputs** high/low. Only unconnected **inputs**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it is an output, simply leave it unconnected.

If you try to connect it to a power rail directly, it will just short out the supply when the flip flop output is driving to the opposite rail. If you connect via a resistor, it will just waste power - there will be a voltage drop across the resistor when the output is opposite from the resistor's bias supply rail.

Answer (score 2):

Leave it disconnected, if you're not using it.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you never tie unconnected **outputs** high/low. Only unconnected **inputs**.